# How to solve PHPunit test with Reg conflicts with comments

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

as you can see in the code

```
/**
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
* @expectedExceptionMessageRegExp /Right.*/
*/
public function testExceptionMessageMatchesRegExp()
{
throw new InvalidArgumentException('Some Message', 10);
}
```

The `/Right.*/` conflicts with the comments.
and when I remove the `*` to test something else (eg. /???/), there's no failed message.
how did this happen?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
* @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
* @expectedExceptionMessageRegExp |Right.*|
*/
public function testExceptionMessageMatchesRegExp()
{
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Some Message', 10);
}
```

Use another character as delimiters such as pipe.